# Classifying groups of order 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $4$ then either $ G \cong C_4$ or $G \cong C_2 \times C_2$

the proof my lecture gave goes as follows:

Let $x \in G$ then by Lagrange $\text{ord}(x)$ divides $|G| =4 $ so w ehave either

1) $\exists x \in G$ with $x^4 = 1$

or 2) $\forall x \in G, x^2 = 1$

He then goes on to prove the theorem. I already don't understand this step and how it splits to 2 cases.

We have the $\text{ord}(x) $ divides $4$ so either $\text{ord}(x) =1, 2, 4$ if $\text{ord}(x) =1$ then $ x = 1$, what group does this give us?

if $\text{ord}(x)  = 2$ why does this result in $"\forall x \in G, x^2 = 1"$ why is it $\forall x$ whereas in case 1) when $\text{ord}(x) =4$ we have $\exists x$ why is one for all and one is there exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is basically about logic, not algebra.

As you have stated, every $x\in G$ has order $1,2$ or $4$.  So there are two possibilities:

- there is an element of order $4$;
- there is no element of order $4$.

In the second case, every element must have order different from $4$, and therefore order $1$ or $2$, because these are the only remaining possibilities when $4$ is eliminated.

Now (in the second case), if $x$ has order $2$ then $x^2$ equals $1$ by definition.  If $x$ has order $1$ then $x^1=1$, and so $x^2$ still equals $1$.

Comment: why can't it be "every x in G has order $4$" why is it only 1 $x \in G$ with order $4$?

Comment: I didn't say **only** one element of order $4$.  Just think about the logic.  For example, I have never met you, but I can still say for sure that **either** you have a brother over $40$ years old, **or** you don't.

Comment: thank you that makes sense

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

We should really pick a *nonidentity* $x \in G$. If we pick an $x$ and it just so happens that $o(x) = 1$, then $x$ must be the identity element. If we pick the identity element, we don't learn anything: Every group has one of those; it's no help distinguishing between two groups!

The two cases are really:

- There exists some element whose order is $4$, or
- There is no element whose order is $4$.

In either case, the order of an element has to be $1, 2,$ or $4$, based on Lagrange's theorem. But in the second case, if *nothing* has order $4$, then everything has to have order $1$ or $2$. But there's a unique element of order $1$ in a given group, the identity element. Therefore, every *nonidentity* element must have order $2$, in the second case.

Comment: thank you for your response and apologies for not accepting it, I simply looked at the other answer first, but it did help!

Comment: No problem at all! David's answer was quite good, it's a good thing you looked at it first :)